# Range auto send in email body

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any code to send a range in an email body if a certain time in a range is exceeded. This should be automated and not a button.

Comment: Yes, you can use an OnTime-event. Have your tried anything yourself, so far?

Comment: @eirik thanks for your precious time. Here is the code which i have made till yet. i am unable to post it as it is showing at it is too long.

Comment: I don't need to see all of it, just what regards the particular operation you want to do here. The easiest way to show it is probably to just edit it into the original question. If you want to give it a go on your own, I'd recommend you to have a look at [`OnTime`-events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx), as already mentioned

Comment: Oh i go this. bit where should i map this code on my code. I work for a Call center and i have prepared a Break tracker in which people mark their breaks. when they go home they click a button and all the data gets captured on the email and it is sent via email to a email id. Employees do not click on that button and we have to manually track the data from the email.

Comment: So what you need to know is how to pull the data from the email to Excel?

Comment: I was Unclear at first part would explain once again. I have a excel sheet in which agents mark their breaks. There is button in where the code copies the desired range to the email and sends it out to the email id designated. But some agents don't do so. Hence, i wanted it to be automated that before logging out from the shift the email goes out with that range.

Comment: So what is it you lack in your code? If it is that it should be autosent every x hours, set an `OnTime`-event which when it times out sends the email and sets a new timer.

Comment: i am lacking it sending automatically at the desired time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the email-sending sub to run at a set time every day, the easiest thing to do is to use the [`OnTime`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx). In your case, you would put something like this in the `ThisWorkbook`-module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call new_timer
End Sub
```

and something like this in a standard module:

```
Sub email_sending_macro
  <your code to send the email>
  Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
  Call new_timer
End Sub

Sub new_timer
  Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:00:00"), "email_sending_macro"
End Sub
```

This should set your code to run at 4 o'clock every day. The [`Application.Wait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851.aspx) is there just in case the macro takes less than a second to run, you do not want it to send more than one email, do you? :)

Comment: I will work on this on Monday and get back to you if any query.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you mark it as solved if it works for you.

Comment: I Worked on this but still not working for me can you write the whole code for me and i will try it out and also should this code be put in excel or outlook.